# Format fill colours for cells based on formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, conditional-formatting

Conditional formatting in Excel allows only three colours. I need four colours. The only 4-colour choice available is based on the fourth colour being less than the minimum value. I need the fourth colour to be greater than the maximum value.

I am working on a balanced scorecard table. Sample cells as follows:
[image]

I need the cells to be formatted as follows: if `<A2` then red fill, if `>= A2` `<B2` then yellow fill, if `>= B2 <C2` then green fill, if `>= D2` then blue fill

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using an older version of Excel that only supports 3 conditions (Excel supports many more than that since 2007), one way to support 4 colors is to set the default color of the cell to one of the outliers (say blue in this case) and set conditions for the other three colors:

```
<A2: Red
>= A2, <B2: Yellow
>= B2, <C2: Green
```